# People sometimes see different profile picture in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, profile-picture

When I shared a Google sheet with a Yahoo! account user they saw my word press account profile picture instead of my Gmail profile picture. How do I change this? I'm willing to unlink accounts or delete my WordPress if that is possible. I just need to know how to change this.

Answer (score 1):

Simply update your Yahoo profile picture or create profile if you don't have one. Put the same picture tag you have on Gmail an wait.

Remember spec about pic should be:

- Image file size: 5MB (maximum)
- File format: .jpg, .png, .jpeg
- Image resolution size:192x192 (minimum)

Yahoo uses your profile from Yahoo and if you don't have one they take the pic from WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo and Google are competitors.  So, they use their own picture of you, not of the other company.
It is the same that happens when you try to open a PDF file in GDrive, with Adobe Reader.  It does not allow you.
I do not know the solution though.  The last case is happening to me right now.
Best regards,
Laura